# Is it possible to make a two slider MotionLayout in Android?

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

**Problem:** I'm trying to make a sliding view similar to the first example on this [examples page](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout/examples) but instead of one slider I want two or more sliders. Is that possible to do in one scene with ConstraintsLayout 2.0.2 or do I need to make multiple scenes with a single slider in each?

I have looked at multiple examples on multiple sites but I can't find anything that shows two items being animated independently of each other. The closest thing I have found is the example on the link provided labeled Multi-State which is located at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. MotionLayout has a single value "progress" which moves from 0 to 1.
You can have 2 motionlayouts in another layout and each is a slider.